# Videos downloaded from video hostings are seeked too slowly

Tags: video, video-conversion

Videos downloaded from youtube and other video hostings are seeked too slowly in video player. How to add an index to them under Windows (flv and mp4 files)? A bat file that makes anything needed would be preferred.

Comment: Do you have examples of videos that seek faster? Where did those come from?

Comment: Yes, from torrents :) I've heard it's so slow because youtube videos don't have an index and must be read sequentially till the place you need.

Comment: Which video player on which OS? Have you tried using a different (better) player?

Comment: All videos have an index of some sort. You can't add an index later, really. The only thing I could imagine is that the video streams have different intra frame intervals. Without specific examples that's hard to prove though.

Comment: For example - just download any big video from youtube, where you can feel a difference between seeking a file with or without sequenital reading till the place you wanna seek to.